# Specifying a function in Django settings

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I write a Django app which should have a setting whose value is a Python function.

How to put the function into `settings.py`? To use a function name I would need to import the module defining the function from `settings.py`. Is it good idea to import something from `settings.py`?

Any other way to specify a function?

Comment: What is the purpose of the function?

Comment: The `User` model can be defined in the settings, so you could also put a function name. However, you'd need to ensure the API is identical. Fro mthis point of view, I'd go by creating a base class  with the desired API (like an interface really) and then follow the same approach as `User` has.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye The function returns an `Organization` object, based on the current user and probably also on user settings (in some of our projects there may be more than one organization per user, thus we cannot determine the organization from the user)

Comment: There isn't any `Organization` or model object for that matter when the settings are not yet loaded. Don't do this.

Comment: *thus we cannot determine the organization from the user*, huh? Why not extend your model to use a ForeignKey?

Comment: We do not request `Organization` object when the settings are not yet loaded. In fact we request it from a HTTP request

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I mean that we can determine the organization from the user *in the same way for all our projects*. So every project needs a special function for this. Well, now I've got an idea: we can use a `User` method for this